# In WebApi2, how to retrieve resultset from stored procedure and reflect back to Angular Page

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Creating a web app, where data is being retrieved from a SQL Server stored procedure to a controller class in Web Api 2. I want to access the values of the resultset in the controller.

The result set will be sent back to model, using Angular uri.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_ToBeInitiate(
    @status varchar(50),
    @retVal int output)
AS
BEGIN
    select 
        INITIATED_FOR, [emp name],  
        INITIATED_by, REQUESTED_DATE, 
        UPLOADED_LOA, UPLOADED_Bg_Check_Form
    from 
        tbl_User t , tbl_INITIATED I, tbl_SUBJECT_FORM S 
    where 
        t.[Emp No] = I.[INITIATED_FOR] 
        and S.[Emp No] = I.INITIATED_FOR 
        and i.PROGRESS_STATUS = @status



    SET @retVal = 100 --It is to check whether I am getting correct Output value
END
GO
```

Procedure is returning the expected output.

Here is controller class method :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ToBeIntiated))]
    [Route("api/ToBeInitiated/{status}")]
    public IHttpActionResult ToInitiated(string status)
    {

        var retVal = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "retVal", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int };

        var locstatus = new SqlParameter("status", SqlDbType.VarChar,255);
        locstatus.Value = status;

        using (var x = new DB_BgCheckEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<ToBeIntiated> toBeInitiated = x.Database.SqlQuery<ToBeIntiated>
                           ("proc_ToBeInitiate @status,@retVal out", locstatus, retVal).ToList<ToBeIntiated>();

            foreach (WebApplication12.DTO.ToBeIntiated i in toBeInitiated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.EmployeeID);
            }

            if ((int)retVal.Value == 10)
            {
                 return Ok(toBeInitiated); 
            }
            else{
                return NotFound();
            };

        }
```

> `var toBeInitiated` is not returning resultset, though in Sql Server, values are being populated.

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Before using `retVal.Value` check `retVal` for not be null ;).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: retVal is not null, I have already checked that. And thanks for pointing out in Stored Proc, I will change the join style.

Answer (score 0):

The null reference exception comes from the fact that retVal.Value is null and you are trying to cast it to an int primitive.

The reason is likely found in the following line:

```
var retVal = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@val", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int };
```

you are setting `ParameterName` to `"@val"`, but in the sproc it's named `"@retVal"`.

Comment: after correcting the error as mentioned, still getting Null from procedure.
Currently done this in proc : `set @retVal =10`. So value is not coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter name from @val to @retval in the following line

```
var retVal = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@retval", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int };
```

Comment: after correcting the error as mentioned, still getting Null from procedure.
Currently done this in proc : `set @retVal =10`. So value is not coming out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @RetVal int
Declare @status varchar(50)
exec GetEmployees @status = @status out , @retVal =@RetVal out
```

Comment: Proc is running in a healthy state in sqlserver, but in C#,output parameter of proc is not returned.

Comment: i'm sorry i posted without typing the whole thing, actually i meant to put these query within  x.Database.SqlQuery<ToBeIntiated>() function.

Comment: this is also not working, can you please write the clean code, I am getting _internal query error.

Answer (score 0):

Output parameters are set after resulting dataset(s) are read.

Please go through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx), it may help you.

**Edit:**

You have to do something like below:

```
 var idParam = new SqlParameter {
     ParameterName = "id",
      Value = 1};
 var votesParam = new SqlParameter {
      ParameterName = "voteCount",
      Value = 0,
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
 var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<Person>(
     "GetPersonAndVoteCount @id, @voteCount out",
      idParam,
      votesParam);

 var person = results.Single();//This line is important

 var votes = (int)votesParam.Value;
```

I can not see

> ok(resultsetobject)

in your code.

Comment: I read this blog many a times but not able to get its use. As, data has to be sent to back to server so no use of iterating it, that's why `return ok(resultsetobject)`

Comment: I meant `return Ok(toBeInitiated) else return NotFound()`. Currently I am able to get value of Output Parameter, but resultset count is still 0. I am updating my code in my question.

Comment: Did you check with SQL Server that it returns data when you executed sp with same status?

Comment: yes I checked that, its returning the correct output, this is the code which I am using for the executing procedure, `declare @status varchar(50)
declare @retVal  int 
set @status='to be initiated'
exec proc_ToBeInitiate @status,@retVal out
select @retVal`

Answer (score 0):

So, finally able to resolve my error. 
Here are few things that friends here and I did, to resolve my error :

1. Using `Exec proc_name @var1,var2` - I got to know that in VS2013 `Exec` is unnecessary, and might be it was one of the reasons for error :

   > the sqlparameter is already contained by another sqlparametercollection
2. Find the difference between `dbcontext.Database.ExecuteCommand` and `dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<Tentity>`. Former is used for commands like, Create, Update, Delete, Insert, while later is for Select query.

   > Earlier I was using dbcontext.Database.ExecuteCommand();
3. ResultSets are of type IEnumerable, and when there is output parameter, iterate the resultset. For Ex:

   ```
   foreach (WebApplication12.DTO.ToBeIntiated i in toBeInitiated)
           Console.WriteLine(i.EmployeeID);
   ```

Then only, output parameter of stored procedure is available.

4. Add `.ToList<Tentity>`, if resultset variable is passed in your model, otherwise your resultset won't be converted into JSON data. Ex:

   var resultSet = dbcontext.Database.SQlquery
   ("storedproc @a",a).ToList();
   return Ok(resultSet); //Data in Json Format will be sent back to model

   > Also, TEntity property's name should be same as the column name, which stored procedure will return. This is mentioned SQLQuery definition.
5. Finally, my error, value of status passed in the stored procedure from was wrong.

   > Value is case-sensitive, which I found in my case.

PS : Thanks everyone for resolving my issue. Please feel free to correct my concepts.
Reference : 
[To retrieve the output parameter, resultset should be iterated.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx)
Credit @Nilesh